# How to restart PHP on Windows? Unable to find the socket transport "ssl"

Tags: windows, php, iis, openssl

I am trying to load the openssl module, I uncommented it in the `php.ini`:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

But when running my script I get an error:

> Failed to connect: 0 Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did
>   you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

From the PHP documentation:

> After activating an extension, save php.ini, restart the web server
>   and check phpinfo() again. The new extension should now have its own
>   section.

I am using a windows server machine, This is production, I really don't want to reboot the server, is there an alternative?

Comment: what type of server do you have ? "Appserver" "wampserver" ??? you have to find httpd.exe process and kill it then restart it

Comment: @k3rnel31 its IIS, sorry I forgot to mention

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To restart `PHP` on `IIS`, you actually need to restart `IIS`:

```
Click Start, click Run, type IISReset, and then click OK.
```

Comment: IISreset is overkill. For most applications. Restarting the application pool is sufficient for most purposes and should be done first.

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> `iisreset`

Or, more verbose: `iisreset` inside a powershell opened as administrator - or even inside a Cygwin shell.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For those that stumbled upon this answer and you're running Windows 10 or another version with PHP but you're NOT running any of the usual web server apps (WAMP, ServerDesktop, IIS, etc), open your task manager and you will probably see "CGI/Fast CGI" which is the PHP. Right-click and end task. The app will not go away but instead, restart with your updated configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that, instead of restart IIS entirely, it's just enough to restart the Application Pool associated with the specific site.

By IIS Manager, first click the Site name on the left panel, then "Basic Settings" on the right panel, so you can see what's the associated application pool. Finally go to "Application Pools" section, click the proper pool and then click "restart" on the right panel.

Answer (score 0):

To restart PHP on IIS, you actually need to restart IIS:

**Go to Start -> click Run -> type iisreset, and then click OK.**

If **iisreset** command is not recognized, then

1. Click win -> search "**Turn windows features on or off**"
2. Tick the checkbox "**Internet Information Service**"
3. click **ok** and after completion try the above process again.